# SQL Server 2012, update record based on next record

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

I'm struggling to find a solution to **update** (not just select) SQL table records based on previous values. I can get the script to populate the immediate subsequent record with the LAG() function, but when I have the same values in a row (like 'CC' below) I can't get it to populate with the next value that's not the same as the current value.

It would also be helpful to be able to add CASE/WHEN condition so that only values with the same BaseID are evaluated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my desired result:

```
BaseID  Value  Date        NextValue
1       AA     2017-10-01  BB
1       BB     2017-10-02  CC
1       CC     2017-10-03  DD
1       CC     2017-10-03  DD
1       CC     2017-10-03  DD
1       DD     2017-10-04  NULL
2       EE     2017-10-01  FF
2       FF     2017-10-02  GG
2       GG     2017-10-03  NULL
```

Comment: What do you have to define "next". There is nothing in your sample data that you can use to define an order.

Comment: sorry about that, date is the sorting value

Comment: Still you can't really sort these as you have duplicate rows here. But you can do this using DENSE_RANK. Give me a couple and I will post up an example

Comment: can you have multiple values for a given date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the distinct baseid,value,date combinations and use `lead` to get the next value in a cte and use itto `update`.

```
with cte as (select t1.baseid,t1.value,t1.nextvalue,t2.nxt_value
             from tbl t1 
             left join (select t.*,lead(value) over(partition by baseid order by datecol) as nxt_value 
                        from (select distinct baseid,datecol,value from tbl) t
                       ) t2 
             on t1.baseid=t2.baseid and t1.datecol=t2.datecol and t1.value=t2.value
             )
update cte set nextvalue=nxt_value
```

This assumes there can't be multiple values for a given baseid,date combination.

Comment: This should actually be a little better for performance than my solution but the formatting here make this difficult to decipher.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using DENSE_RANK as another option.

```
declare @Something table
(
    BaseID int
    , MyValue char(2)
    , MyDate date
    , NextValue char(2)
)

insert @Something
(
    BaseID
    , MyValue
    , MyDate
) VALUES
(1, 'AA', '2017-10-01')
, (1, 'BB', '2017-10-02')
, (1, 'CC', '2017-10-03')
, (1, 'CC', '2017-10-03')
, (1, 'CC', '2017-10-03')
, (1, 'DD', '2017-10-04')
, (2, 'EE', '2017-10-01')
, (2, 'FF', '2017-10-02')
, (2, 'GG', '2017-10-03')
;

with SortedResults as
(
    select *
        , DENSE_RANK() over(partition by BaseID order by BaseID, MyDate ) as MyRank
    from @Something
)

update sr set NextValue = sr2.MyValue
from SortedResults sr
join SortedResults sr2 on sr2.MyRank - 1 = sr.MyRank and sr.BaseID = sr2.BaseID


select *
from @Something
```

Comment: This fails. Next Value in your Update is not defined in your CTE.

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien really??? Did you actually try it? NextValue is absolutely defined in the cte. The cte has select * and the table has NextValue.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the nextvalue in the table variable and left it out of mine. Was expecting to see it in the CTE. You are correct.